# ORA-01722: invalid number - Python with cx_Oracle

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle, bind-variables

I have the below script inserting into an Oracle database. If I manually put all the passed in values into an INSERT statement and run the hardcoded statement in Python the INSERT works but for some reason when I use the below way it always fails with an `ORA-01722: invalid number`.

I thought it was original the datetime value so I tried `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(:9, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`, it didn't make any difference.

Spent ages trying different suggestions from SO and the internet but no luck as of yet.

```
data = ['NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2', 'Test Text', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2017-06-02 16:00:00', '20180910122315440220.csv']

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(env.DB_USER, env.DB_PASSWORD,cx_Oracle.makedsn(env.DB_HOST, env.DB_PORT, env.DB_NAME));

# Disable auto commit.
conn.autocommit = False

cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = """INSERT INTO TESTDB (TESTDB_ID, TESTDB_ACYR_CODE, TESTDB_SEM_CODE, TESTDB_MODULEID, TESTDB_STU_PIDM, TESTDB_COMPONENT_ID, TESTDB_COMPONENT_NAME, TESTDB_GRADE_MARK, TESTDB_GRADER_PIDM, TESTDB_GRADE_MODIFIED_DATE, TESTDB_CREATION_DATE, TESTDB_FILENAME, TESTDB_ACTIVITY_DATE, TESTDB_USER_ID) VALUES(TESTDB_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, TO_DATE(:9, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), SYSDATE, :10, SYSDATE, USER)"""

cursor.prepare(sql)

cursor.execute(sql, data)

conn.commit()

cursor.close()

# Enable auto commit.
conn.autocommit = True
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not due to `DATE`. You used `TO_DATE` for converting it to date, which should work fine.

The problem is due to NUMBER columns, for eg: `TESTDB_ID` and you are trying to insert string 'NULL' into them. Note that python does not convert quoted string "NULL" to Oracle NULL by default. To do that you should use Python `None` type.

So, your data should be

```
data = [None, None, None, None, '2', 'Test Text', None, None, '2017-06-02 16:00:00', '20180910122315440220.csv']
```

and your insert statement contained in `sql` variable ( with to_date ) should work normally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the values in your `data` array with the projection of your table `TESTDB`. Make sure that the datatypes of the dictionary entries match the datatypes of their target columns.

However, I'm going to guess that one or more of the columns assigned `'NULL'` is numeric, and what's happening is that your code is inserting a **string** of `'NULL'` rather than a null value. Try replacing the `'NULL'` assignments with empty strings or maybe a Pythonic `None`, and see whether that solves the problem.